Converting XFA Form to Static PDF in C# for Browser Compatibility
I have this C# code and I am trying to convert an XFA form into a standard static PDF so that it can be opened in a browser. Unfortunately, the code converts the XFA form in such a way that the expected result is not present in the output file. Could you please advise me on how to modify the code?"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using iText.Forms;
using iText.Forms.Fields;
using iText.Kernel.Colors;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;

namespace iText.Samples.Sandbox.Acroforms
{
    public class RemoveXFA
    {
        public static readonly String DEST = @"C:\temp\xfa-form-filled.pdf";
        public static readonly String SRC = @"C:\temp\xfa-form.pdf";

        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            // Ensure the destination directory exists
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(DEST);
            file.Directory.Create();

            // Create an instance of RemoveXFA and manipulate the PDF
            new RemoveXFA().ManipulatePdf(DEST);
        }

        protected void ManipulatePdf(String dest)
        {
            // Open the source PDF and prepare to write to the destination PDF
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(dest));
            PdfAcroForm form = PdfFormCreator.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);

            // Remove the XFA form from the PDF
            form.RemoveXfaForm();

            // Get all form fields from the PDF
            IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetAllFormFields();

            // Iterate over the form fields
            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, PdfFormField> name in fields)
            {
                // Check if the field name contains "Total"
                if (name.Key.IndexOf("Total") > 0)
                {
                    // Set the field color to red
                    name.Value.SetColor(ColorConstants.RED);
                }

                // Set the field value to "X"
                name.Value.SetValue("X");
            }

            // Close the PDF document
            pdfDoc.Close();
        }
    }
}





The result is this content instead of an actual standard PDF
Please wait...
If this message is not eventually replaced by the proper contents of the document, your PDF
viewer may not be able to display this type of document.
You can upgrade to the latest version of Adobe Reader for Windows®, Mac, or Linux® by
visiting http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html.
For more assistance with Adobe Reader visit http://www.adobe.com/support/products/
acrreader.html.

I think what you probably want to do, is to flatten the XFA form (XFAFlattener). A full example.

Yes, I need to flatten the PDF, exactly like what this online service does: https://itextpdf.com/demos/flatten-dynamic-xfa-pdf-free-online.
I tried that example, but it seems like some metadata needs to be specified. It doesn't appear to be universal for any XFA form.

that online service uses the API I've linked you to

Thank you. When I try the code from the full example, I get an error in VSC: 'Program.cs(4,27): error CS0234: The type or namespace name xtra does not exist in the namespace iTextSharp.tool.xml. (Are you missing an assembly reference?).
In csproj have

"Could you please help me?

well, you need to either use iText 5, or iText 7 (or 8), not both. They you need the pdfXFA package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext.pdfxfa (in this case, I'd say iText 8).

Thank you so much. I use   



and get error "Unhandled exception. System.NotSupportedException: AbstractITextEvent is only for internal usage" with C# code

can you share all the dependencies you have on your project now? just the itext related ones.

Can I send you program.cs and itextfalltenxfadocument.csproj via email? It will be faster. Thank you very much

no, but feel free to post a link to GitHub, or similar services

https://github.com/frantisekrysl/itext-xfa

I will load your project later, but just taking a quick look at the repo, please bear in mind that pdfXFA only supports .NET Framework >= 4.6.1.

Thank you so much. That’s it, no more trouble. It’s finally working now. You’re the best. I have updated project.
